# How can I exempt some routes to not hit 404 error if the URL don't match as exact?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have an app layout like this:

```
function App() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <Header />
            <main className="py-1">
                <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
                <Container>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} exact />
                        <Route path="/sitemap" component={SiteMap} exact />
                        {/* SOME MORE ROUTES LIKE THESE .... */}
                        <Route path="*">
                            <Error404 />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Container>
            </main>
            <Footer />
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

I am setting an Admin Page and I don't want to put it into Container for some reason like I want to set a sidebar just for the admin page if I put this into the container then it becomes ugly not look like a side bar and I don't want to change the layout of the container as well it's working well for the other components. But if I put the Admin component outside the container then `<Switch>` thinks it's not a valid URL and the Both `Admin` + `<Error404 />` components loads Simultaneously.

So I want to put some logic here that the Route:

```
<Route path="*"><Error404 /></Route>
```

should ignore the URL starting with /admin and which is not wrapped in the `<Switch>` tag and not hit with the `Error404`

Is that possible? Is there any other approach to do the same?

Comment: Why the Switch inside the Container? You can add the Container inside the Switch and only components that you want will be inside the Container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if I put the Admin component outside the container then `<Switch>`
> thinks it's not a valid URL and the Both `Admin` + `<Error404 />`
> components loads simultaneously.

This is because the `Router` component ***inclusively*** (*i.e. all matches*) matches and renders routes while the `Switch` ***exclusively*** (*i.e. only one match*) matches and renders them. Since both the `"/admin"` `Route` and `Switch` are both rendered by the `Router` then they both can potentially match.

You can use more than one `Switch` in your router. Render an "outer" switch to match and render either the "/admin" route, or everything else, and use the "inner" switch as-is. Now the 404 route is rendered on the "other" route in the inner switch.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <main className="py-1">
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" component={Admin} />
        <Route>
          <Container>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" component={HomeScreen} exact />
              <Route path="/login" component={LoginScreen} exact />
              <Route path="/sitemap" component={SiteMap} exact />
              {/* SOME MORE ROUTES LIKE THESE .... */}
              <Route path="*">
                <Error404 />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </Container>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
      </main>
      <Footer />
    </Router>
  );
}
```